# Why is nested goroutine necessary?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm working on MIT 6.824 - [lab1](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-1.html)(part III) and get confused at a piece of scheduling program of a (mini) mapreduce:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < ntasks; i++ {
    task_arg := DoTaskArgs{ JobName: jobName, File: mapFiles[i], Phase: phase, TaskNumber: i, NumOtherPhase: n_other }
    //not so relevant

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        reg_worker := <- registerChan
        call(reg_worker, "Worker.DoTask", task_arg, nil)
        go func() { registerChan <- reg_worker }()
        //registerChan <- reg_worker
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
```

This program

1. deploy 100 tasks to 2 worker (with `call`) from channel `registerChan`
2. put worker back to channel when task finished
3. `wg.Add()`, `wg.Done`, `wg.Wait()` to sync

how `schedule` is called (https://github.com/WentaoZero/mini-mapreduce/blob/master/master.go#L84):

```
ch := make(chan string)
go mr.forwardRegistrations(ch)
schedule(mr.jobName, mr.files, mr.nReduce, phase, ch)
```

`registerChan` is not buffered.

I try removing `goroutine` at line `go func() { registerChan <- reg_worker }()` to make it: `registerChan <- reg_worker`

the program gets stuck after more than 50 tasks are done. I suppose it proves that the goroutine is working but I don't see why it gets stuck.

`registerChan <- reg_worker` has been written in a goroutine, why is it necessary to wrap it with another goroutine?

I don't think the rest of the system is relevant so I won't post it here. You may check https://github.com/WentaoZero/mini-mapreduce if needed. This scheduling program is picked from https://github.com/WentaoZero/mini-mapreduce/blob/master/schedule.go

Comment: reg_worker := <- registerChan is a blocking call. So trying to read from the channel registerChan in the same go routine will not work. are you sure it works for 50 tasks?

Comment: @sahaj I'm sure there are more than 50 tasks done.

Comment: Nothing in the included code suggests why it should complete 50+ tasks and get stuck before completing all 100. The reason should be in the rest of the code, which makes this off-topic.

Comment: Is registerChan buffered?

Comment: @britt No it's not. Just add some explain.

Answer (score 0):

the inner goroutine is quite nessesary since the registerChan is not buffered!

Sending to unbuffered channel is blocked unless it's been received. In your case, you got 100 tasks, which means that both `reg_worker := <- registerChan` and `registerChan <- reg_worker` will be called 100 times. Seems that sending/receiving is balanced, right?

However, you still got 2 workers! There must be something like `registerChan <- new_worker` somewhere in your code(most likely `mr.forwardRegistrations(ch)`), and it should be called 2 times!

Therefore, you have two more sending than receiving on a unbuffered channel, so the last 2 `registerChan <- reg_worker` are blocked, then `defer wg.Done()` and `wg.Wait()` are blocked as well!

To verify it, you could debug like this:

```
        defer wg.Done()
        reg_worker := <-registerChan
        call(reg_worker, "Worker.DoTask", task_arg, nil)
        fmt.Println("### start sending to registerChan")
        registerChan <- reg_worker
        fmt.Println("### send done")
```

just count the occurrence number of these two sentences. It should be 100 and 98!

Comment: I'm working on 6.824 as well, I would suggest you put `wg.Done()` before `registerChan <- new_worker` rather than using inner goroutine.